Vue3EasyDataTable missing default export
I have project with Laravel 11 + Vue 3, and I'm using there Vue3EasyDataTable.
Everything works on dev, but when I try to build project with npm run build I got error:

resources/js/app.ts:17:8 - error TS1192: Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/pflegedirekt_laravel/node_modules/vue3-easy-data-table/types/main"' has no default export.
17 import Vue3EasyDataTable from 'vue3-easy-data-table';

I have no idea how to fix it and I cannot find any solution or advice online.
app.ts
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h, DefineComponent } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';

import 'vuetify/styles';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

// import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
// import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css'

import Vue3EasyDataTable from 'vue3-easy-data-table';
import 'vue3-easy-data-table/dist/style.css';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Pflegedirekt';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
})

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob<DefineComponent>('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .use(vuetify)
            .component('EasyDataTable', Vue3EasyDataTable)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});

And this is how imported Vue3EasyDataTable looks like:
export type SortType = 'asc' | 'desc'

export type FilterComparison = '=' | '!=' | '>' | '>=' | '<' | '<=' | 'between'| 'in';

export type Item = Record<string, any>

export type FilterOption = {
  field: string
  comparison: 'between'
  criteria: [number, number]
} | {
  field: string
  comparison: '=' | '!='
  criteria: number | string
} | {
  field: string
  comparison: '>' | '>=' | '<' | '<='
  criteria: number
} | {
  field: number | string
  comparison: 'in'
  criteria: number[] | string[]
} | {
  field: string
  comparison: (value: any, criteria: string) => boolean
  criteria: string
}

export type Header = {
  text: string
  value: string
  sortable?: boolean
  fixed?: boolean
  width?: number
}

export type ServerOptions = {
  page: number
  rowsPerPage: number
  sortBy?: string | string[]
  sortType?: SortType | SortType[]
}

export type ClickRowArgument = Item & {
  isSelected?: boolean
  indexInCurrentPage?: number
}

export type UpdateSortArgument = {
  sortType: SortType | null
  sortBy: string
}

export type HeaderItemClassNameFunction = (header: Header, columnNumber: number) => string
export type BodyRowClassNameFunction = (item: Item, rowNumber: number) => string
export type BodyItemClassNameFunction = (column: string, rowNumber: number) => string

export type TextDirection = 'center' | 'left' | 'right'

Update
I found same error on GitHub and they solution is to add
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

to tsconfig.json, but it didn't work for me.

Typescript is correctly complaining that the vue3-easy-data-table lib doesn't have a default export.. Why are you using this instead of vuetify data tables anyway?

@WesleyCheek to be honest i forgot about them even though I'm using vuetify. Thanks for reminder, Im gonna use it.
